# How to add colour to the action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I was wondering how to add colour to the action bar. I tried looking on the android development website but I couldn't understand it. I am trying to add a light blue colour to my action bar. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom theme with the name CustomTheme and add it to your application tag in your manifest.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.XYZ</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Holo.ActionBar.XYZ" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#00A1DE</item>
    </style>
```